# Getting issue after redeployment of apache-cxf web service in tomee server

Tags: java, rest, cxf, apache-tomee

I created web service using apache-cxf and using johnzon provider for marshalling and unmarshalling of JSON and also configured provider-service in open-ejb-jar file. Once I deploy the application in tomee sever, I can access my api but after un-deployment and again deployment of my application. I can not access my api using http://localhost:8080/demo/school-services/student/1

**I am getting below error.**

```
<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"><ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/johnzon/mapper/ac`enter code here`cess/FieldAndMethodAccessMode$CompositeReader</ns1:faultstring></ns1:XMLFault>
```

**Below is my configurations file *openejb-jar.xml* file**

```
<openejb-jar>
        <pojo-deployment class-name="jaxrs-application">
            <properties>
                # optional but requires to skip scanned providers if set to true 
                cxf.jaxrs.skip-provider-scanning = true 
                 cxf.jaxrs.providers = johnzon,org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.EJBAccessExceptionMapper 
            </properties>
        </pojo-deployment>
    </openejb-jar>
        resources.xml file 


<resources>

        <Service id="johnzon" class-name="org.apache.johnzon.jaxrs.ConfigurableJohnzonProvider">
        # 1M 
        maxSize = 1048576 
        bufferSize = 1048576 
        # Additional types to ignore 
        ignores = org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.MultipartBody 
      </Service>
    </resources>
```

Please find attached demo application git repo:https://github.com/dharmendrasahu08/spring_boot_application/tree/master/demo
Could you please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks,
D Sahu

Answer (score 0):

It looks like json converter issue - your code is using Apache Johnzon to convert a Java object to Json which is in container and not in deployment archive. You can try either changing json provider to use jettison or jackson-jaxb adding the libraries if using maven add the dependency :

```
org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:x.y.z
```

Or to try to enforce it to be loaded from the webapp  add in conf/system.properties:

```
openejb.forced-load=org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider
```

Try changing openejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <openejb-jar xmlns="http://www.openejb.org/openejb-jar/1.1" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openejb.org/openejb-jar/1.1"> 
     <pojo-deployment  class-name="jaxrs-application"> 
         <properties> 
             cxf.jaxrs.providers =  org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider 
         </properties> 
     </pojo-deployment> 
 </openejb-jar>
```

Comment: I have done the changes but API is not getting up.Getting 404 error.